# scanf is using an uninitialized variable; C

Tags: c, char, initialization, scanf

I'm sure there just a silly mistake here, however, I can't figure it out. 
This is part of my code:

```
char *moving;
scanf("%s", moving);
```

When I compile it with gcc, it says the following:

```
newmatrix.c:38:7: warning: ‘moving’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Line 38 is the scanf

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: `moving` is a pointer. What does it point to? Nothing. That is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate memory for `moving` before using it. Use `malloc()`.

`moving` is pointer of `char` type. Before storing the string in `moving`, you need to allocate memory for it.

```
char *moving;
moving = malloc(100); 
scanf("%s", moving);
```

OR

Simply change `char *moving` to `char moving[256]`.

Also instead of `scanf()` use `fgets()`.

Comment: Better use `scanf("%99s",moving);` but I would recommend `getline` (which does not the same thing as the `scanf`, which stops on spaces).

Answer (score 5):

You can allocate memory before you call `scanf()`.  For example:

```
char moving[256];
if (scanf("%255s", moving) != 1)
    …oops — presumably EOF…
```

You could use `malloc()` instead of a simple array, but then you have to remember to free the allocated memory.  OTOH, if you want to return the data from the function where it is read, it may well be more convenient to use `malloc()`, but consider passing a pointer to the space (and its size?) to the function.

Or you can have `scanf()` do the memory allocation for you (check the manual page for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) carefully — read it weekly until you've memorized (enough of) it):

```
char *moving;
if (scanf("%255ms", &moving) != 1)
    …oops — probably EOF, but perhaps OOM (out of memory)…
…use moving…
free(moving);
```

Yes, this is one of the lesser-known options in POSIX-standard `scanf()`; it is not a part of Standard C.

Answer (score 1):

allocate memory to the pointer before using it

```
char *moving;
moving = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", moving);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. And why `malloc`? Given the information in the question, `char moving[100];` works just as well.

Comment: i gave malloc because he seem to want to use pointers. 
and, sizeof(char) is 1 by defination, thats why i gave 100*sizeof(char)

Comment: Well, the OP is also confused by a very simple warning, so he seems to be a beginner, and what he *wants to use* is not necessarily what he *should be using*. And you wrote `100 * 1` knowingly because it's more expressive than writing `100`?

Comment: i wrote 100 * 1 so that he would know that using sizeof inside a malloc call is a better practice.